# How do I schedule a SQL Server Full-Text rebuild in SSMS2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a question about scheduling a rebuild and reorganize of a SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Catalog.  When I go to the catalog's Properties then Population Schedule, the wizard seems pretty straight forward except for I don't see a way to specify that I want a rebuild rather than a reorganize.

I wanted to schedule a reorganize to be more frequent with a rebuild at a longer duration.  Could someone assist me in the best way to handle this?  I thought SSMS would be a piece of cake in this regard but I'm clearly missing something and Google hasn't been my friend this time.

Below is a link to the picture of the SSMS schedule I created and you can see when I select from the Population Type, my only choice is "Catalog - optimize".  (I'd embed the image in the post but I guess I need more reputation points, sorry)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G65y5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand still why the other choices don't show up in SSMS but ultimately what I did was just create a population schedule/job that performed a Full-Text Catalog REORGANIZE.  I then scripted out this newly created job and changed the command to do a REBUILD instead.  It works fine so I guess it solved my need but I would love to hear if anyone knows why it doesn't show up in SSMS properties window for the Full-Text Catalog.